# Should we merge the [training] tag and the [practice] tag? How are they different?

Tags: discussion

I am trying to clean up our "tags" a bit; I am bored and unemployed. I have edited two tags and added some explanation. I came across this now: there is a [training](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/training) tag and a [practice](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/practice) tag.

How are they different? And are they different enough to warrant two tags?

The existing explanation for the [training](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/training) tag is

> The **practice** of martial arts. How, what, where, when, why.

And the existing explanation for the [practice](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/practice) tag is

> **Practice**; **training**; using a martial art for the purpose of building strength, speed, muscle memory, refining or learning techniques. Use this tag when your question focuses on learning your martial art in a non-competitive environment, either supervised or unsupervised practice.

Is there an instance where only one is applicable and the other is not? I think that these two tags could be merged into one. It will create less confusion when a user is trying to select  the right tag. [Training](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/training) is *"the process of learning the skills you need to do a particular job or activity"*, and to learn something, one needs to practice. Basically, when one is training, they are practicing their craft.

If that is not something the community wants to do, then we should discuss (here) the factors that make them different, so we can add some explanation in the body of the tags and improve them.

Comment: Hmm, I agree with you that they should be merged. I would do it myself if I had 42 more reputation.

Comment: I agree, these are used as synonyms here. As a native speaker of English I sometimes use practice in another sense though. Definitely a case for merging them

Comment: Agreed on my part too.

Comment: I've created a synonym, which is the first step. https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/tags/training/synonyms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First a general comment: the tags have largely been neglected, and there is plenty of room for improvement in them. Thank you for taking the time to work on them.

I am personally in favor of making this change, and from chat it appears the consensus is to retain the more popular [training](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/training). I will leave time for someone to dissent before pushing through this change as a moderator. In the meantime, do not let this dissuade you from casting your own vote if you are eligible.

---

[practice](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/practice) has now been merged into [training](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/training).

Answer (score 3):

To differentiate the tags, I wonder if "practice" could mean the daily discipline and mindset of martial arts vs "training" which is the actual drilling of moves to achieve body memory and  technical competence.

Training includes instruction. Practice can happen without a teacher present. Maybe it's just semantics and one should be deleted. Which one is more popular?

Comment: Thanks for writing. It appears that others agree "training" is the more complete tag, as can be seen from the comments and the other answer. I too believe this. For me, topics that can be tagged as "practice" can almost always fall under "training". For example, I think the "mindset of martial arts" can be said to be about "training one's mind" and so the better tag would be "training". In addition, a question about "training equipment" such as *"What are the advantages of using a double-end bag?"* would be better suited with a "training" tag than a "practice" tag.

Comment: [You can see the usage of tags here.](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/tags) There are also tags for [drills](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drills) and [exercise](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exercise) and [self-training](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-training).